# Is it possible to add a small poll/quiz in my email and recieve responses?

Tags: html, email, html-email

I want to make a small quiz in my email, but I dont know if it is possible to send information from my email to my server. Anyone knows if it is possible?

Comment: Yes you can add a HTML Form or Links. They usually would be submitted by HTTP to your application.

Comment: Just as @eckes said: `Yes you can add a HTML Form or Links. They usually would be submitted by HTTP to your application.` **BUT** only works on a few email clients.

Answer (score 1):

You cant make a functional  within an email, since Javascipt/POST/GET are considered phishing from the client. But what you can do, is make the first question on the mail, and then on the click, redirect to the next question on your landingpage (with the first answer as a parameter). 
We have done this a few times.

Comment: People creating surveys do this a lot, some call it quickstart.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. I am doing it today. You can create a standard simple form with radio buttons or text fields and send off the result. The caveat is that you would need a web site to process the results.

As Syfer mentions above, it doesn't work on all email clients. It doesn't work in Outlook, so you would need to create a link to the poll web site instead.

Comment: Found this link which I think will be useful in your comment. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2007/11/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/. Maybe add as a table with timestamp from site as to when it was compiled.